# UIsearch bar not returning data to table

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uisearchbar

Edited code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell==nil) 
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (isFiltered) {
   int rowCount=indexPath.row;
   Aves *filtrada=[filteredTableData objectAtIndex:rowCount];
   cell.textLabel.text=filtrada.name;
   NSLog(@"mostrando: ");
    }else {
        int rowCounter=indexPath.row;
        Aves *author=[theauthors objectAtIndex:rowCounter];
        cell.textLabel.text=author.name;
    }
NSLog(@"mostrando: ");
return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        int i;
        [filteredTableData removeAllObjects];
        for(i=0;[theauthors count]>i;i++)
        {
          Aves *name=[theauthors objectAtIndex:i];
            //NSLog(name.name);
            NSRange nameRange = [[name.name lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[text lowercaseString]];
            if(nameRange.length>0)
            {
                [filteredTableData addObject:name];
                NSLog(name.name);
            }
        }
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

Edit: After working on it a while I solved some problems.Just updated my code, the problem is the repaint of the tableView, every thing else go ok. Check it and give any ideas you have plz ^^

Thx again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally fixed it. Here is my working code, thx you all =)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (isFiltered==TRUE) {
        int rowCount=indexPath.row;
        //for (rowCount=0; rowCount<[filteredTableData count]; rowCount++) {
        Aves *filtrada=[filteredTableData objectAtIndex:rowCount];
        cell.textLabel.text=filtrada.name;
        //}

    }else if(isFiltered==FALSE) 
    {
        int rowCounter=indexPath.row;
        Aves *author=[theauthors objectAtIndex:rowCounter];
        cell.textLabel.text=author.name;
    }
    return cell; 
}
```

> -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text {
>
> ```
>   [filteredTableData removeAllObjects];
>
> filteredTableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
>
> if(text.length == 0)
> {
>     isFiltered = FALSE;
> }
> else
> {
>     isFiltered = TRUE;
>     int i;
>
>     for(i=0;[theauthors count]>i;i++)
>     {
>         Aves * filtrado=[[Aves alloc]init];
>         filtrado=[theauthors objectAtIndex:i];
>         //NSLog(filtrado.name);
>         NSRange nameRange = [[filtrado.name lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[text lowercaseString]];
>         if(nameRange.length>0)
>         {
>             [filteredTableData addObject:filtrado];
>
>         }
>     }
>     [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil
> ```
>
> waitUntilDone:NO];
>       }
>        }

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using prototype cells?  I just had a similar problem in one of my projects.

When search results are displayed and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, the table view passed in the the table belonging to the search results controller, not your main table view.  Problem with that is, the search results table view doesn't know anything about your table's prototype cells, so `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns nil.  But just alloc/init'ing a UITableCellView won't give you one of your prototype cells, so whatever UI you laid out in your storyboard isn't there.

The fix is easy: in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, don't call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` on the tableview passed in; just call it on your main table view.  So basically, just change this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) 
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

There's no need for the nil check; Apple's [Storyboards Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011297-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5) says:

> The dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method is guaranteed to return
>   a cell (provided that you have defined a cell with the given
>   identifier). Thus there is no need to use the “check the return value
>   of the method” pattern as was the case in the previous typical
>   implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: just tried it, I get some new errors now when I compile but I will keep working on it, thx a lot man.  The error is the next one Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
  //If the requesting table view is the search display controller's table view, return the count of the filtered list, otherwise return the count of the main list.

     if (isFiltered)
     {
       return [filteredTableData count];
     }
     else
     {
       return [theauthors count];
     }
  }
```

Replace method:

```
   -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
   {
     if(text.length == 0)
     {
       isFiltered = FALSE;
     }
     else
     {
      isFiltered = true;
      int i=0;
      [filteredTableData removeAllObjects];
      filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      //for (Aves* name in theauthors)
      for(i=0;[theauthors count]>i;i++)
      {
        Aves *name=[theauthors objectAtIndex:i];
        NSRange nameRange = [[name.foodName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[text lowercaseString]];

        if(nameRange.length>0)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:name];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: replace it with what? already tried like 8 different ways to do it and still I can't do a crappy search

Comment: replace your method (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text with mine

Comment: thats what I did but no results, reading it now you just copy pasted mine? can't see any diferences

Answer (score 0):

does your app hits this code if(nameRange.location ==0) ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code piece of

```
else
{
    isFiltered = true;
    int i=0;
    [filteredTableData removeAllObjects];
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //for (Aves* name in theauthors)
    for(i=0;[theauthors count]>i;i++)
    {
        Aves *name=[theauthors objectAtIndex:i];
        NSRange nameRange = [name.foodName rangeOfString:text ];

        if(nameRange.location ==0)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:name];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

to

```
else
{
    isFiltered = true;
    int i=0;
    [filteredTableData removeAllObjects];
    //filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; not needed
    //for (Aves* name in theauthors)
    for(i=0;[theauthors count]>i;i++)
    {
        Aves *name=[theauthors objectAtIndex:i];
        NSRange nameRange = [name.foodName rangeOfString:text ];

        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:name];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: thx for you help man, still nothing, don't really understand where is the problem, if you have any other idea It would be great ^^

Comment: Then let's go to basics, when you put some breakpoints to this method, which parts are executed and which parts are not? Or does the method even get called?

Comment: just edited the code, I get to the table view reload data but just put all cells to white.

Comment: NSLog the search text `text` at the start of the method and check to see if the code inside the `for` loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

with in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

The reason because you're not getting use of the dequeued cell anyway.